# Add Filter in SearchView with Room and RecyleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview, android-room, android-filterable

*(google translate)*

**Intro:**
I have searched for this solution, but did not find it. If there is a duplicate of this problem, please let me know. thanks.

**Problem:**
I created a storage application with the Room database and RecycleView. Then I looked for ways to add **Search** to my data. Everything went smoothly, but there was one problem.
If the search word is reduced, then the search is limited to visible data. (Look at the screenshot)

1. [Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J72G.jpg)
2. [Search is done (Normal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT7LQ.jpg)
3. [Empty word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNoSj.jpg)
4. [Search again and The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeypM.jpg)
5. [GIF Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeuxP.gif)

I hope you understand.
Please help me. I have seen a lot of tutorials but nothing works.

thank you

My Code:
Filter in my **Adapter**

```
public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                List<Barang> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    filteredList.addAll(namaBarang);
                } else {
                    for (Barang row : namaBarang) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        if (row.getNamaBarang().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = filteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                namaBarang = (ArrayList<Barang>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

**MainActivity**

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
         //   t = newText.;

            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
```

And I have this too in my Adapter:

```
void setBarangs(List<Barang> barangs){
    namaBarang = barangs;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved with this:

```js
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            List<Barang> listHasilFilter = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Barang> listYgAkandiFilter = new ArrayList<>();
            listYgAkandiFilter.addAll(namaBarangC);
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                listHasilFilter = listYgAkandiFilter;

            //    namaBarang = listYgAkandiFilter;
                Log.d(TAG, "" + namaBarang.size());
            } else {
                for (Barang row : namaBarangC) {

                    // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                    // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                    if (row.getNamaBarang().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                        listHasilFilter.add(row);
                    }
                }

            }

            FilterResults hasilFilter = new FilterResults();
            hasilFilter.values = listHasilFilter;
            return hasilFilter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults hasilFilter) {
            namaBarang = (ArrayList<Barang>) hasilFilter.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Thanks